The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. ERROR 503
Im trying to add cloudfront viewer request as trigger in lambda function but getting this error
503 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
The Lambda function associated with the CloudFront distribution is invalid or doesn't have the required permissions. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

This is my terraform code:
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { App, TerraformStack } from 'cdktf';
import { AwsProvider } from '@cdktf/provider-aws/lib/provider';
import { LambdaFunction } from '@cdktf/provider-aws/lib/lambda-function';
import { IamRole } from '@cdktf/provider-aws/lib/iam-role';
import { IamRolePolicyAttachment } from '@cdktf/provider-aws/lib/iam-role-policy-attachment';
import { S3Object } from '@cdktf/provider-aws/lib/s3-object';
import { CloudfrontDistribution } from '@cdktf/provider-aws/lib/cloudfront-distribution';

class MyStack extends TerraformStack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
        super(scope, id);

        new AwsProvider(this, 'AWS', {
            region: 'us-east-1',
            accessKey: '',
            secretKey: '',
        });

        const lambdaBucketName = '';
        const lambdaBucketKey = 'test.zip';

        const lambdaS3Object = new S3Object(this, 'LambdaS3Object', {
            bucket: lambdaBucketName,
            key: lambdaBucketKey,
            source: 'test.zip',
        });

        const lambdaRole = new IamRole(this, 'LambdaRole', {
            name: 'lambda-execution-role',
            assumeRolePolicy: JSON.stringify({
                Version: '2012-10-17',
                Statement: [
                    {
                        Action: 'sts:AssumeRole',
                        Effect: 'Allow',
                        Principal: {
                            Service: [
                                'lambda.amazonaws.com',
                                'edgelambda.amazonaws.com'
                            ]
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
        });

        new IamRolePolicyAttachment(this, 'LambdaBasicExecutionRole', {
            role: lambdaRole.name,
            policyArn: 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole',
        });

        const lambdaFunction = new LambdaFunction(this, 'LambdaFunction', {
            functionName: 'testing-la-lambda',
            role: lambdaRole.arn,
            handler: 'index.handler',
            runtime: 'nodejs18.x',
            s3Bucket: lambdaBucketName,
            s3Key: lambdaS3Object.key,
            publish: true,
        });

        new CloudfrontDistribution(this, 'CloudFrontDistribution', {
            origin: [{
                domainName: '',
                originId: 'test',
            }],
            defaultCacheBehavior: {
                allowedMethods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                cachedMethods: ['GET', 'HEAD'],
                targetOriginId: 'test',
                viewerProtocolPolicy: 'redirect-to-https',
                lambdaFunctionAssociation: [{
                    eventType: 'viewer-request',
                    lambdaArn: lambdaFunction.qualifiedArn,
                }],
                forwardedValues: {
                    queryString: false,
                    cookies: {
                        forward: 'none',
                    },
                },
            },
            enabled: true,
            isIpv6Enabled: true,
            defaultRootObject: 'index.html',
            priceClass: 'PriceClass_100',
            restrictions: {
                geoRestriction: {
                    restrictionType: 'none',
                },
            },
            viewerCertificate: {
                cloudfrontDefaultCertificate: true,
            },
        });
    }
}

const app = new App();
new MyStack(app, 'my-app');
app.synth();


When invoking the cloudfront Distribution domain name getting the error above.
Do someone know how to fix or what im missing in my terraform code?
